# How to check private state in unit testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I have read some discussions on the internet. They say that we should not unit test private methods or check private state because that's implementation detail and a sign of bad design. But in my case, I really don't know how to do better.

Here is an example code (my actual code is angular using factory, but I try to create a same case using plain js so that everyone is easier to understand because the same cause is closure):

```
function closure(){
    var state = {};

    return {
        refreshState : function(property1,property2) {
            state.property1 = property1;
            state.property2 = property2;

            //store these properties into localstorage
        },
        getState: function () {
            if (!state.property1) {
                state.property1 = //retrieve from localstorage
            }
            if (!state.property2) {
                state.property2 = //retrieve from localstorage
            }
            return state;
        }
    };
};

var objectToTest = closure();
```

In my real app, I can inject and mock the local storage, but it's a question here. 
My question is how to test that the `refreshState` method sets its private state because I cannot verify its value:

```
state.property1 = property1;
state.property2 = property2;
```

I'm thinking about stubbing the local storage and use the `getState` method to get the state. But it looks like integration test because the `getState` has its own logic that I cannot get rid of.

Comment: I hope I understand your question correctly, but I would suggest that if you are worried about state.property1 and state.property2 being set, you should test that property1 and property2 args are valid and throw an error/exception if not.  Then using your unit test you can monitor for an exception being thrown rather than having to verify the literal values.

Comment: @rpaskett: there is no check on these properties, they're strings with any value.

Comment: Right, I mean if you do something like `if(typeof property1 !== "string" ) { throw new Error() }`, that will ensure your state.property1 is being assigned a valid value, if not an error is thrown and your unit test can check for that (assuming your unit test framework can indeed monitor for thrown errors).

Answer (score 0):

Spy on a localStorage mock and assert that it was called with some params, otherwise you're testing two things, that `refreshState` does its job AND `getState` does its job.

```
describe('closure', function () {
  it('#refreshState', function () {
    var localStorageSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('window.localStorage', ['setItem',]);

    var closure = closure();
    closure.refreshState('params', 'params2');
    expect(localStorageSpy.getItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('params', 'whatevs');

  });
});
```

Comment: Sure that I will mock the localStorage (that's what I'm doing). In the refreshState, I want to test 2 things: the state in memory is updated, the state is saved to localstorage (I can test this by mocking local storage) but I cannot test that the state in memory is updated.

Comment: If you want to be sure that your in memory state is up-to-date then you would have to add further checks and implement exception handling that you can test for - what you want to test is so specific that it should not depend on actual values but rather the flow of the method.